# Imported object into unity lighting not working correctly

Tags: light, import, shaders, normals, unity

So the jist of it is I'm trying to get a toon shader to work on imported object from blender, I get this terrible looking jagged lighting in unity. [image]

( **the left tombstone ignore the one on the right** )And I dont think it is the shader because I will put the default surface shader in unity on the object with the same jagged result.

I've talked with both unity and blender people and haven't been able to resolve it. From what people tell me the normals are all correct on the model.

[image]

I've played with smoothing and auto smooth in blender but the top image is the best result I have gotten.

The import settings in unity dont seem to help much either. The top image set to the following import settings.

[image]

And setting the Normals to Import gives me this.

[image]

I dont know if this is the right place to post this but like I said I have a feeling (*With my limited knowledge of unity and blender*) that this is a blender/ import issue because the official unity surface shader gives the same result.

Any help, links or advice on how to get that jagged lighting to be smooth is greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you UV map the model before exporting?

Comment: Yes I did a Smart UV Project with default settings.

Comment: Went through a video of manually unwraping with marking seams and that didn't change anything either

Answer (score 0):

Real-time lighting and toon shading are both very dependent on mesh geometry since smooth shading only applies to shading with vertex normals and not raytraced shadow calculation that only accounts for vertex positions. With toon shader you are going to need more subdivisions on curved surfaces.

So now you have a 180 degree arc expressed in 5 edges. Try making the arc with 9 or 19 subdivisions and you will see the quality improve.